# Is it possible to create multi column layout with paging in html?

Tags: html, css, razor

At the bottom of the "page" (some specified height), content flows to the next column. Once that column fills up as well, it flows down to the next "page".'s like the difference between a scroll which has been divided into columns, and an ordinary book whose pages have been divided into columns.see the image attached [image]

Comment: So you actually want a html code of above layout...???

Comment: Hi @Rakin, StackOverflow doesn't provide a resource to have markup built for you. I'd suggest looking into tutorials online regarding pagination (like http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_pagination.asp) and then start following a guide to build a prototype. If you then have trouble, you can return to SO and provide an example of your work so people can help you more directly. Good luck!

Comment: wait let me make a fiddle for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sulution for the above problem is found in the below link. pasting it for future referances.
http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/
http://welcome.totheinter.net/autocolumn/sample10.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ed1swp9/10/) I hope it will suffice your purpose. Don't forget to include bootstrap

```
.item {
background: #F4F5F7;
border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}
.border-fine{
border-top:0px;
border-right:0px;
}
.border-right{
 position:relative;
}
.border-right:after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 999;
 top: 5px;
 left: 5px;
 right: 5px;
 bottom: 5px;
 border-right: 2px dashed #ccc;
 }
```

Comment: not exactly....we cant make the content in two div per page. its dynamic  data. length of each paragraph cant be determined